# How to pass system properties to self-contained Java applications on the command line

Tags: java

I have a self-contained Java application packaged with the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html) tool (version 8.0, Windows). How do I pass it system property values at application runtime (not at package time) on the command line?

[The doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html) does not seem to  address this.

I tried the standard Java way as in:

```
mypackagedapp.exe -Dmyprop=myvalue
```

but that does not appear to have an effect.

Comment: What do you mean by "not appear to have an effect"? How do you go about to retrieving the property?

Also, I strongly doubt that the standard Java way includes running an `exe`-file.

Comment: System.getProperty("myprop") returns null. When I invoke my code instead using java.exe -Dmyprop=myvalue -jar...  it returns "myvalue" as expected

Comment: Ah misread your question.. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#CEGBCJEB

Comment: @Tobb:  Same link I posted?? How does it address my question? Can you elaborate?

Comment: FWIW, I just posted a [similar but more general question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30809330/1207769) about passing arguments to the JVM via the JavaFX self-contained application launcher, which would include system properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that validates if an argument exists in the command line.

See if the next code can help you.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    CommandLine line = validateArgs(args);
    if (null == line) {
        return;
    }
}

private static CommandLine validateArgs(String[] args) {
    Options flags = getArgs();
    CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
    CommandLine line = null;

    try {
        // parse the command line arguments
        line = parser.parse(flags, args);
        if (line == null) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (ParseException exp) {
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
    }
    return line;

}

static Options getArgs() {
    Options flags = new Options();
    Option dmyprop = OptionBuilder.withArgName("dmyprop")
            .hasArg()
            .withDescription("add description")
            .create("Dmyprop");
    flags.addOption(dmyprop);

    return flags;
}
```

In order to get environment variable you need to use:

```
        String env = System.getenv(option);
```

where `option` is your desired environment variable.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Could you please explain whats going on in your code?

Comment: @Igor: Thanks! I understand I can potentially write my own parsing for setting system properties. I just have a hard time believing that Java stops doing that for you as soon as you package your app to be self-contained. So I guess I'm hoping for an answer that either shows how Java does it in the case of self-contained apps or that points to this as a documented limitation of self-contained apps.